# Cannot read property '0' of undefined on Single Sign On service using node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am developing a small application which uses single sign on service for the login procedure but when I run the app.js script, I get the following error:

```
var ssoConfig = services.SingleSignOn[0];
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

and I am really don't know what is wrong because the JSON which is created automatically by IBM Bluemix and which maintains the env variables seems correct. The entire JSON file is:

```
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "SingleSignOn": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "authorizationEndpointUrl": "...",
     "clientId": "...",
     "issuerIdentifier": "...",
     "secret": "...",
     "serverSupportedScope": [
      "openid"
     ],
     "tokenEndpointUrl": "https://sso-ahttzn6qt8-co15.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token"
    },
    "label": "SingleSignOn",
    "name": "sso",
    "plan": "standard",
    "tags": [
     "security",
     "ibm_created",
     "ibm_dedicated_public"
    ]
   }
  ],
  "cloudantNoSQLDB": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "host": "...",
     "password": "...",
     "port": ...,
     "url": "...",
     "username": "..."
    },
    "label": "cloudantNoSQLDB",
    "name": "Cloudant NoSQL DB-vj",
    "plan": "Shared",
    "tags": [
     "data_management",
     "ibm_created",
     "ibm_dedicated_public"
    ]
   }
  ],
  "iotf-service": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "apiKey": "...",
     "apiToken": "...",
     "base_uri": "...",
     "iotCredentialsIdentifier": "...",
     "mqtt_host": "...",
     "mqtt_s_port": ...,
     "mqtt_u_port": ...,
     "org": "..."
    },
    "label": "iotf-service",
    "name": "Internet of Things Foundation-gp",
    "plan": "iotf-service-free",
    "tags": [
     "internet_of_things",
     "Internet of Things",
     "ibm_created",
     "ibm_dedicated_public"
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "486b73db-6a73-4536-8de2-0d8f517761b0",
  "application_name": "buyonthefly-group4",
  "application_uris": [
   "buyonthefly-group4.mybluemix.net"
  ],
  "application_version": "05eaa8ee-81d8-42bd-a340-a618bbcdf342",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 256
  },
  "name": "buyonthefly-group4",
  "space_id": "a719f5fe-7835-490a-b646-928e601a5341",
  "space_name": "Exercises",
  "uris": [
   "buyonthefly-group4.mybluemix.net"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "05eaa8ee-81d8-42bd-a340-a618bbcdf342"
 }
}
```

So services contains SingleSignOn, cloudandtNoSQLDB and iotf-service.

This is the app.js script:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
   done(null, obj);
});

var services = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES || "{}");
var ssoConfig = services.SingleSignOn[0];
var client_id = ssoConfig.credentials.clientId;
var client_secret = ssoConfig.credentials.secret;
var authorization_url = ssoConfig.credentials.authorizationEndpointUrl;
var token_url = ssoConfig.credentials.tokenEndpointUrl;
var issuer_id = ssoConfig.credentials.issuerIdentifier;
var callback_url = 'http://buyonthefly-group4.mybluemix.net/auth/SSOLogin';

var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
        authorizationURL : authorization_url,
        tokenURL : token_url,
        clientID : client_id,
        scope: 'openid',
        response_type: 'code',
        clientSecret : client_secret,
        callbackURL : callback_url,
        skipUserProfile: true,
        issuer: issuer_id
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
    });
});

passport.use(Strategy);
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {}));

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/auth/sso/callback', function(req, res, next) {               
    var redirect_url = req.session.originalUrl;                
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect: '/hello',                                
        failureRedirect: '/failure',                        
    })(req,res,next);
});

app.get('/hello', ensureAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
    request.send('Hello, '+ request.user['id'] + '!\n' + '<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Login failed');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<h1>Bluemix Service: Single Sign On</h1>' + '<p>Sign In with a Social Identity Source (SIS): Cloud directory, Facebook, Google+ or LinkedIn.</p>' + '<a href="/auth/sso/callback">Sign In with a SIS</a>');
});

var appport = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8888;
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var server = app.listen(appport, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Anyone could help me to find out where I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you have in `services.SingleSignOn` ?

Comment: what do you have in `services`?

Comment: services has the items named by "SingleSignOn", "Cloudant" and "InternetOfThings" and each of them has other variables (like credentials, clientId etc.) as you can see in the SingleSignOn part of the JSON above. @BipBip services.SingleSignOn has credentials, authorizationEndpointUrl, clientId, and so on, which are the things shown in the JSON above.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trivial question: Are you running this code on Bluemix? This error occurs when you try to run the application on an environment which doesn't contain the VCAP_SERVICES env variable (e.g. your machine).

Comment: Thank you so much to everybody and especially to @Umberto. I didn't know this and I was still trying to run  the app locally. On bluemix it didn't work for other silly errors and I thought they were all realated so I had fixed the issue by saving thé object SingleSignOn in a different JSON file and I was parsing form there(I know this doesn't look nice but it worked for me) but now that I fixed them it works fine also on bluemix. Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted it as an answer, what about accepting it in order to provide quick reference for future viewers?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to run the application on an environment which doesn't contain the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable (e.g. your machine). 
Since you are not running in Bluemix the following instruction:

```
var services = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES || "{}");
```

Will result in the *services* variable being an empty object. For this reason *services.SingleSignOn* is *undefined* and you get the `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error.

Be sure that you are running your application on Bluemix.